# Dgrid ColumnHider does not show/hide columns on column resize

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I am seeing an issue where ColumnHider does not properly show/hide columns once the column is resized. The columnHider works fines when the grid loads the first time. However, if i resize any column, the columnHider gets messed up. It does not show/hide columns and this looks very buggy with dgrid using ColumnHider and ColumnResizer in conjunction.

This issue is reproducible with any dgrid demo( github demo as well). I have seen quite few open issues that are similar, but they have not been addressed yet. Did anyone dealt with the similar issue and came with a workaround? What would be the robust way to handle this issue

Comment: post your code here !

Comment: Hi, it even reproducible on basic dgrid demo. I am not able to post my code as it depends on lot of things and i can't get it working here